# The changes applied in javascript will be returned after postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want visible a control on ClientUploadComplete in AsyncFileUpload.

```
 <cc1:AsyncFileUpload ID="ImageFileUpload" Width="400px" OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete"/>
```

I use a function for visible my control. When it is complete, the visiblity that control will be true.

```
function uploadComplete(sender, args) {
        var filename = args.get_fileName();
        var id = '<%= Session["ID"].ToString()%>' + "." + filename.split('.').pop();
        document.getElementById('FileImage').setAttribute('src', 'Temp/' + id);
        var btn = document.getElementById('<%= RemoveImageButton.ClientID  %>')
        btn.style.visibility = 'visible';

    }
```

But after a postback, the visiblity that control will be false.

Answer (score 0):

Set some other control like hidden field while post back as follows.

```
 function uploadComplete(sender, args) {
    var filename = args.get_fileName();
    var id = '<%= Session["ID"].ToString()%>' + "." + filename.split('.').pop();
    document.getElementById('FileImage').setAttribute('src', 'Temp/' + id);
    var btn = document.getElementById('<%= RemoveImageButton.ClientID  %>')
    btn.style.visibility = 'visible';
    hid1.val(1);

}
```

and on doucuement. ready check for the hidden field value if it is one set it's visibily accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, but i want to know why did it happen?

Comment: You have set the values through the jquery so the server is not aware about the visibility of the cotrol. And after the post-back the visibility is set to it's initial state.

Comment: I use :`jQuery(document).ready(function () { var exe = ocument.getElementById('<%= Extension.ClientID  %>'); if (exe.value != "") { var btn = document.getElementById('<%= moveImageButton.ClientID  %>')btn.style.visibility = 'visible';    }    });` but don't run in postback

Comment: You set the visibility in jQuery right? Means it 'moveImageButton'  was not visible at the time of the page load right? But as you said it is `after a postback, the visiblity that control will be false` after post back it went to initial stage that is visibility to false?

Comment: Yes, in updatecomplate, the visibility that control set visible, but when i chnage selected index of a dropdownlist in updatepanel, the visiblity will be false.